# What is the meaning of "tops" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> we would see the Sun on his journey, crossing between the building
> tops from our side over to the RPO Building side.

Does it simply mean "roofs"? So why "tops" and not "top"? Or why building and not building**s**?

Could you explain it to me?

The fuller text:

> when we were new, Rosa and I were mid-store, on the magazines table
> side, and could see through more than half of the window. So we were
> able to watch the outside – the office workers hurrying by, the taxis,
> the runners, the tourists, Beggar Man and his dog, the lower part of
> the RPO Building. Once we were more settled, Manager allowed us to
> walk up to the front until we were right behind the window display,
> and then we could see how tall the RPO Building was. And if we were
> there at just the right time, we would see the Sun on his journey,
> crossing between the **building tops** from our side over to the RPO
> Building side.

Answer (score 2):

**Tops** means roofs, or the upper edge of the buildings that the narrator can see.

It is **tops** because there is more than one building that the author can see, and the sun is moving from one to another.

It is **building** and not *buildings* because this is a construction called a *noun adjunct*, using one noun (*building*) to modify another (*tops*).  When we use a noun adjunct, we don't pluralize the noun adjunct: for example, a *horse race*, not a *horses race*, even though there is more than one horse.